# Is there any way to draw Webbrowser content to a specific DC?

Tags: com, winapi, webbrowser-control, gdi, iwebbrowser2

These days, I tries to create a hiden WebBrowser control in my program, and Using the IViewObject interface draw to my custom DC.

The result is fine, I got All the content I want, but the Draw speed is unacceptable, especially some complex web pages which contains Flash objects, **Each Draw to DC cost more than 100 ms**. So the flash object I drew is not smooth.

**Is there a fast way to draw the control to my a specific DC?**

my code sinpet is like this:

```
//hCompDc is a CompatibleDC which select a CompatibleBitmap.
RECTL imageRect = {0, 0, nWidth, nHeight};
pHtmlDocument2->QueryInterface(IID_IViewObject, (void **)&pViewObject);
pViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, NULL, NULL, NULL, hCompDc, NULL, &imageRect, NULL, 0);
```

Thank you for reading this question.

Waiting for your answers~

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Daniel
I'm trying to get the WebBrowser's content smoothly, and draw it to some else where, like DirectX surface, or MemDC. And better if I can hide the original Browser UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way to do this.  None of the components you're using--IE, Flash, etc--were designed to be used this way.  If draw time is an issue, you have to do it on a separate thread and synchronize.

Comment: I thought using mutithread can helps the UI look smooth, but the Browser content is still not smooth? Did I think wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I try to create a thread call the OleDraw Function, but I don't know how to do the synchronize with the COM interface. the call in "OleDraw" will always raise an exception. I can only use the WM_PRINT to do it in separate thread:(.

Comment: Sure it is:), but COM Multi-threaded I think is even more harder, which I lost my way~

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wke/

```
char* buffer = new char[800*600*4];
IWebVeiw* webView = wkeCreateWebView("");    
webView->resize(800, 600);
webView->loadURL("www.google.com");
webView->paint(buffer, 0);
wkeDestroyWebView(webView);
```