# HTML renderer drop-in, C++ code

Tags: c++, user-interface, html-rendering

I want to drop in an HTML renderer that will basically be used for render-to-texture operations.

If I can render the HTML to an HDC, that would be perfect.

I found [HTMLayout](http://www.terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/), which isn't bad.  But it isn't open source.  But I'm wondering if there's a way to somehow tap into IE or Mozilla/Gecko code, how realisitic/difficult this will be, and possibly some pointers on how to do it.

It will be for a regular straight C++ directx application

## Edit

Wow!  [Mozilla has an embedding kit!](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/embedding/)

Comment: http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines

Comment: See here for a windows-only approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950331/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at WebKit.

Comment: As used by safari and others.

Answer (score 0):

Qt can do it, render to a QPainter. See for example http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwebpage.html But not sure if it's easily used if you are not already using Qt.